# Python: how to get each element in a str list and then put the first element into the first file in a directory, second element in the second dir?

Tags: python, list, file, file-processing

I'm trying to deal with txt files.

I have a 2D list called `reps = [], len(reps) = 41,` I also have a directory called `replies`, which contains `34 txt files`.

I want to do like this:

- `reps[0][0]` is the first line of the `file1.txt` under the replies directory, `reps[0][1]` is the second line etc.
- `reps[1][0]` is the first line of the second `file2.txt`
- Until all `34 txt` files have been replaced then it's done

how can I achieve this?

I would be very appreciate

Comment: if `len(reps) = 41` but there are only 34 txt files in the directory, what should happen for the extra entries in `reps`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
reps = ...
for i, lst in enumerate(reps, start=1):
    with open(f"replies/file{i}.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines(line + '\n' for line in lst)
```

Although if you indeed have 41 lists of strings in `reps`, this will result in 41 files, not 34:

```
replies/file1.txt
replies/file2.txt
...
replies/file41.txt
```

If I misunderstood you and you actually **really** want to just replace exactly 34 files that already exist in that directory, you can always just add a conditional break in the beginning of the loop:

```py
...
for i, lst in enumerate(reps, start=1):
    if i > 34:
        break
    ...
```

Note that [`writelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) expects each element in the provided iterable to provide its own line seperator, which is why the generator produces `line + '\n'` for every line.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably looking something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
for lines, file_path in zip(reps, Path("/path/to/replies/dir").iterdir()):
    with open(file_path, "w") as f:
        f.writelines([l + "\n" for l in lines])
```

1. `Path("/path/to/replies/dir").iterdir()` will let you iterate over all the files in the replies directory.
2. `zip()` will let you iterate over reps and files, and automatically stops iterating after whichever iterable runs out first.
3. `writelines()` will dump all the lines in the lines variable to the file.

Comment: This puts one line in each file.

Comment: That is a strange way to handle criticism. Instead of "oops, right, my bad, fixed it", you complain about it and dismiss the question as "not worthy".

Comment: I have corrected the answer with the help of your comment. Thanks!